# Fetch first element in JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON string, an example is shown in the screenshot below. How can I print to the console the first element from a given array?

I've tried different options for converting a date to a string, but the string won't let me get the first element in its entirety
[image]

Comment: Don't you want to parse into your custom struct? You want to show JSON, or in a more human readable output?

Comment: I just want to get the first element of a given array in its original json format and transfer it to another file. The first thing I want to do is figure out how to print this to the console. I am doing a data parser

Comment: Use `JSONSerialization` to convert `Data` to Array, retrieve first element, then use `JSONSerialization` to convert that JSON Dictionary into Data, and `String(data:encoding:)` to have that string.

Comment: I tried going this way, but I was getting the error
My code: let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data)
Error: Thread 3: "*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write"

Comment: Where? the var `data`, that's a `Data` object? If so, that's the wrong method `data(withJSONObject`, that's for Dictionary/Array to Data, not the reverse.

Comment: Yes, data its a Data object. Can you tell me the right method?

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/Qqx7sEh1 to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a package like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to work with **JSON** in **Swift**. You can add it via Swift Package Manager or CocoaPods, whichever you prefer.

Supposing to have this JSON string:

```swift
let json = "[{\"id\" : 0, \"text\" : \"hello\"},{\"id\" : 1, \"text\" : \"hi\"}]"
```

You can parse it as shown, and then retrieve and print to console the first item:

```
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
        print(json[0])
    }
}
```

This will print on the console as:

```swift
{
  "text" : "hello",
  "id" : 0
}
```

Remember to `import SwiftyJSON` at the top of the swift file

Comment: is it possible to get the first array of the json WITHOUT having to decode the ENTIRE JSON?